# Trouble removing CSS using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello there stack overflowers! I am having a problem creating a list web page in which I have two starting elements and I can add elements and remove elements. I got pretty far through the website but I am running into an issue I have researched and been stumped on for the past hour and a half. Upon running my takeAwayElement function the innerHTML of the element is set to 0, which makes the string disappear, but the problem is that the CSS is still there and it is showing a blue background, I attempted to set the innerCSS to '' but it then resulted in every single list element I had on the web page to become nothing, how do I get around this problem?

Thank you so much if you decide to help me out, It means so much that you read my post and that really shows you care, thank you.

My HMTL

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JS playground</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<h1 id="headerElement" style="text-align: center;">List testing!</h1>
<div class="listDiv">
     <ul class="ulList" id="ulTop">
          <li>Hello World!</li>
          <li>After this element is all added lists</li>
     </ul>
     <script src="list.js"></script>
     <button onclick="addElementItem()">Click me to add a list item</button>
     <button onclick="takeAwayElement()">Click me to take away a list item.</button>
</div>
</html>
```

MY CSS

```
.listDiv {
     width: 800px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     background-color: lawngreen;
     padding: 20px;
}
.ulList li{
     list-style: none;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 10px;
     margin: 5px 0px;
     background-color: lightskyblue;
}
```

MY JS

```
function addElementItem() {
var list = document.getElementById('ulTop');
var newListItem = document.createElement('li');
var newListText = document.createTextNode('NEW ELEMENT ADDED');
newListItem.appendChild(newListText);
list.appendChild(newListItem);
}

function takeAwayElement() {
var list = document.getElementById('ulTop');
var lastItem = list.lastChild;
list.innerHTML = '';
};
```

Comment: I am a bit confused. takeAway() should remove last child right why are you setting whole list to empty string ? It should be `lastItem.innerHTML` right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function takeAwayElement() {
var list = document.getElementById('ulTop');
var lastItem = list.lastChild;
list.removeChild(lastItem)
};
```

Use JS remove child to get rid of the element instead of using `innerHTML`

Comment: Hey man, this is working for the most part! Although one issue I'm having is the list elements I made in the HTML that were not added take two clicks to remove, do you know what could be causing this issue? Thanks so much for your response

Comment: Use `list.lastElementChild` instead of lastChild. Here is a link to JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dvoxhcrp/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in takeAwayElement() :

`lastItem.style.backgroundColor='';`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are emptying the whole list instead of the last item. Secondly, this is not how you REMOVE an element.
Try this and let me know if it works:

```
function takeAwayElement() {
    var list = document.getElementById('ulTop');
    setTimeout(function() {
       var lastItem = list.lastChild;
       list.removeChild(lastItem); // This would remove the element from DOM with no other need to play with CSS
    }, 0);
};
```

Added to this, i'd like to suggest you not to include your scripts in middle of your HTML. Put them either in `<head>` or at last inside `<body>` (preferred method)